# When should new .NET projects be designed for .NET 4 Framework

Tags: asp.net, ruby-on-rails, architecture, .net-4.0

I am preparing to start on a new short-term contract (1-2 months) that involves replacing an Access application by moving it to ASP.NET and SQL Server.

I am only responsible for the ASP part and connecting it to the database.

The only requirement is that whatever technologies I use be relatively well-known in the area, so that if they need to have someone else work on it, it isn't specialized knowledge.

So, I could do this in Rails or ASP.NET, but, when should the development be aiming for .NET 4 Framework, as there are many changes coming out that may be advantageous to use.

Or, even though it may be useful, when is it better to just ignore new features and stay on an older version of .NET?

I am assuming that hardware isn't the limitation, as many computers won't be able to run .NET 4 Framework, but that would be an issue for a hosting company, as they can find a hosting company to support whichever framework the application is designed for.  If Rails makes the most sense, as their hope is to have the application written quickly, but have it reliable, then again, the hosting company would need to support it, or they use a different one.

This company hasn't used a hosting company, they need to find one, so there isn't a relationship that could be an issue.

UPDATE: Part of my concern is that initially the application will not require javascript, but phase 2 will be to make it more interactive, as some clients won't be allowed to have javascript on their computers.  In order to limit how much javascript must be known by a developer there are frameworks that will adapt to browsers and situations fairly well, which is why I am also thinking about RoR and the fact that there appears to be changes coming out in .NET 4 that may help with this.

Comment: What does RoR have to do with .Net? If you're already familiar with ASP.Net, writing this with Rails makes no sense. The idea that RoR web apps can be written in less time than ASP.Net is one of the most bizarre and unsubstantiated myths out there.

Comment: I could write it in either, as RoR may be easier as the application is mostly select boxes and displaying information based on options.  I just can't use something like GWT for this.

Comment: GWT? Sorry, I'm acronymically-challenged sometimes. What you're describing is super-easy in ASP.Net. I'd even suggest just sticking with .Net 2.0, except for the beat-down I'd get (plus LINQ is pretty cool, actually).

Comment: Google Web Toolkit. It could make it easier to have it be more interactive, but in Knoxville, TN, it appears to be a very limited set of developers using it.

Comment: @MusiGenesis: No beat down, more like +1.  ASP.Net 2.0 is solid and will deploy almost anywhere.  We still have clients that are hesitant about upgrading to 3.5.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a general rule of thumb, I wait one year before building sites in a new framework unless the client specifically asks for the newest technology.  This has worked out very well for me.  The advantages are:

- The technology is much more stable (hotfixes, service packs, etc.)
- Common complaints about missing functionality are usually resolved
- Hosting companies, support communities and corporate IT departments have had time to get used to the technology, find out more about it, play around with it and have it mature within their organization

Unless there is specific need for new functionality introduced by .Net 4, there is no point in subjecting your clients to the immediate problems with an initial release, or making it more difficult for them to find hosting.  You should either investigate all of this up-front, or use .Net 3.5 in the meantime.

Comment: My only concern is the difficulty if they want to later move to .NET 4, if they decide to move next year.  By the time this app is ready for commercial use, with all the new features, I expect that .NET 4 will already have been released.

Comment: If you can identify specific gains to be made by moving their app to .Net 4, then this should be weighed against the potential problems mentioned above.  If you're just concerned they're going to move to .Net 4 just for the sake of moving, then it's a red herring.  Concentrate on what will give them the most value.

Comment: Your general rule of thumb and the exceptions helped me. I thought it would be nice to move on, but I will stay with .NET 3.5, except for my own projects.

Answer (score 1):

> The only requirement is that whatever
>   technologies I use that it be
>   relatively well-known in the area, so
>   that if they need to have someone else
>   work on it, it isn't specialized
>   knowledge.

I would have thought that requirement was enough not to develop this project on .NET 4.0 - it takes time for a new framework version to filter down into the market, and it will be a while yet before there are a lot of developers around with .NET 4.0 experience.

Also, you would be essentially developing on top of a BETA product - while I'm sure most of the features will remain unbroken from BETA -> RTM, there is always a risk that something will break or not work like it did in BETA, so why risk this on a commercial project?

I wouldn't target .NET 4.0 yet on a commercial project unless there was a specific reason for doing so, and even then you would have to have buy-in from the client, ie "I can do this much more quickly and with less effort if we use the current beta version X rather than established, stable version Y" - good luck with that.

I worked on a commercial project that used the CTP version of LINQ to SQL - then when we went to VS2008 / 3.5, suddenly everything changed and we had to make a lot of changes just to get LINQ to SQL working again.

Stick with 3.5 - it's easier for hosting and getting developers.

Answer (score 1):

Just a couple of thoughts, I wouldn't even think about creating an application for production use in .NET 4/ASP.NET 4 until:

1. There is a release candidate. It's
   not the first time I've seen
   features in beta's not make it to
   RC/RTM.
2. Microsoft have permitted development and deployment
   of production applications by way of a 'Go
   Live' license.

There are some hosters out in the market such as OrcsWeb who are participating in public beta testing, but they aren't intended for production use.

I'd run with the .NET 3.5/ASP.NET 2.0 or MVC bits for now. Better safe than sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking it's going to be easier finding hosting for a Rails app. If you want to run .net 4.0 you're *probably* going to have to run a VPS or dedicated machine. However if you're bailing after the application is finished and assuming your client is in Knoxville, they're going to have a tougher time finding a Rails developer to maintain the application.

I think the bigger question is your role. They're looking to you to solve this problem for them. Are you productive in both technologies? How about getting a Windows server up and running? A Linux server? How's your SQL Server vs MySql? I'd guess that you're probably stronger on one stack vs the other - for a contract that short I wouldn't want to be doing a lot of experimental development.

Comment: I am actually going to check with a few recruiters to see how many RoR developers are in the Knoxville area.

Comment: I'm sure it's ridiculously easy to find Rails hosting, but it's also ridiculously easy to find ASP.Net hosting, so I don't think that's any basis for picking one or the other. Also, I can't believe I'm defending Rails in any way, but with web apps you don't really need to have a local person supporting an app.

Comment: @James: I'd be *very* wary of what any recruiter says about the availability of good RoR developers locally - they really have no way of telling for sure. This is also true of .Net developers, but .Net developers are common enough that you don't have to rely on what recruiters say.

Comment: @James: my former company (in Louisiana - not New Orleans) went the RoR route, and found themselves utterly unable to find *anybody* to work on the project.

Comment: @Musi - that's for the client to decide whether they want someone close. Some clients like the face to face. *Generally* it's easier to find Rails hosting. It's not difficult to find a Windows host, but Linux is just more commonplace, and usually cheaper.

Comment: @Andy: Linux does seem to be a lot cheaper, but it's usually like $5/month vs. $30/month (unless it's a really high-volume site), so the difference is like 10 minutes of developer time per month.

Comment: If you want to know about RoR developer availability don't call recruiters, hit up the local Ruby group. Us Ruby geeks has this habit of congregating together on normally monthly basis around the world.

Comment: @railsninja: I don't think I've ever heard an RoR developer say "I suck, don't use me", despite the fact that some of you, well, suck. I think I'd actually trust a recruiter first (please note that you could replace "RoR" here with any other language/platform, and the comment would still be true).

Answer (score 0):

i wait until the OS that everyone will be using has it.

Just last month i took a dependancy on GDI+, which first shipped with Windows XP.

Comment: This is for an ASP.NET app, so I am not concerned about the user's PCs.